# Debian: Minimum LibreOffice Packages to Convert docx Files to pdf in Headless Mode

Tags: debian, docker, libreoffice

I'm developing a Docker container with a Debian 10 base image (this is a fixed dependency) that converts docx files to pdf using LibreOffice (soffice) in headless mode.

I've got it working with the following packages installed:

`libreoffice`
`default-jre-headless`
`libreoffice-java-common`

However, when built, the Docker container size is over 1GB. Ideally, I'd like the container to be as small as possible. Is there a way I can find out what are the minimum package requirements to get soffice to run in headless mode and convert the docx files to pdfs?

Comment: `libreoffice` is a metapackage that requires or suggests several packages. Maybe you can install a subset of the dependencies. If you only want to process text documents you could omit packages related to spreadsheets and other document types, like `libreoffice-calc`, `libreoffice-impress` etc. I don't know if you can omit parts of the Java libraries.

Comment: Even with careful selection of libreoffice-* packages, it's probably still going to pull in a lot of fonts, X, and possibly desktop environment packages.   And a bunch of other stuff.  Libreoffice is a GUI app, even at bare minimum it requires a lot of "infrastructure".   Maybe look into [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) instead of LO if docker image size is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no official support for this. I had the same problem with Docker/Kubernetes and solved it succesfully with following approach. LibreOffice v7.5 in this case.

- download the deb-Package from https://de.libreoffice.org/download/download
- extract it, you get about 40-50 deb-files
- I did a trial&error approach and found following set of deb-files to be neccessary for converting DOCX to PDF at serverside:

```
    libobasis7.5-en-us_7.5.4.2-2_amd64.deb
    libobasis7.5-images_7.5.4.2-2_amd64.deb
    libobasis7.5-ooofonts_7.5.4.2-2_amd64.deb
    libobasis7.5-writer_7.5.4.2-2_amd64.deb
    libreoffice7.5-ure_7.5.4.2-2_amd64.deb
    libreoffice7.5-writer_7.5.4.2-2_amd64.deb
    libreoffice7.5_7.5.4.2-2_amd64.deb
```

- put these debs in a separate directory and install via: dpkg -i *.deb
- Test direct conversion:

  `/opt/libreoffice7.5/program/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf ./demo.docx --outdir ./`
- Run daemon:

  `/opt/libreoffice7.5/program/soffice --headless --accept=socket,host="127.0.0.1,port=8100\;urp;" &`
- for a more automated way I repacked the above list of deb-files, deployed and installed them via the DOCKERFILE